# Storing number of times each letter of the alphabet appears in a string in a desired location

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I think I'm not doing it right at all... Am I going in the right direction? I tried to implement loops to check if each letter in the string "beg" matched the letters in the array.

**"beg" is a text that is already provided for my assignment**

```js
//
// ***(15)  store the number of times the letter "a" appears in the string "beg" in 1st location;
// ***      store the number of times the letter "b" appears in the string "beg" in 2nd location;
// ***      store the number of times the letter "c" appears in the string "beg" in 3rd location;
// ***      store the number of times the letter "d" appears in the string "beg" in 4th location;
// ***      etc.
// ***      show the 26 counts on one line separated by commas in the span block with id="ans15"
//



var alphaNum = [26];
var alphabet = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n"
  "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"
];

for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
  alphaNum[i] = 0;
}
for (i = 0; i < beg.length; j++) {
  charNow = beg.substr(i, 1);
  for (j = 0; j < 26; j++) {
    if (charNow == alphabet[j])
      alphaNum = alphaNum[j] + 1;
  }
}


showAlpha = "";
for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
  showAlpha = showAlpha + alphabet[i] + ": " + alphaNum[i] + "<br>"
}

ans15.innerHTML = showAlpha;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`beg` is missing, at `alphabet`, a comma is missing and some other mistakes are inside commented.

At least it is then working code with some small changes.

```js
var beg = 'store the number of times the letter "a" appears in the string "beg" in 1st location;', // declaration missing
    alphaNum = [],          // empty array, not an array with one element 26
    alphabet = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"],
    i, j,           // declaration missing
    charNow,        // declaration missing
    showAlpha = ""; // declaration missing

for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
    alphaNum[i] = 0;
}
for (i = 0; i < beg.length; i++) {         // should be i++
    charNow = beg.substr(i, 1);            // could be replaced by charNow = beg[i]
    for (j = 0; j < 26; j++) {
        if (charNow == alphabet[j]) {      // adding some curly brackets
            alphaNum[j] = alphaNum[j] + 1; // index missing
        }
    }
}
for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
    showAlpha = showAlpha + alphabet[i] + ": " + alphaNum[i] + "<br>"
}

document.getElementById('ans15').innerHTML = showAlpha; // target missing
```

```html
<div id="ans15"></div>
```

Comment: Thank-you so much!! Just learning javascript so thank-you for helping me see the corrections I need to make :D